# How to save change with MVC 2 en EF 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC 2 with EF4. Creating or deleting objects works but update doesn't.
I have read lot and lot tutorials / questions on StackOverflow, but I haven't found a real WORKING code to use in my "Edit" method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Account model)
    {
        try
        {
            Account accountEdited = accountRepository.Get(id);

            // Working code to update "accountEdited" with "model"'s values ???

            accountRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**I'm using EntityFramework with WCF Data Service**

Comment: What is the code of `Save` method?

Comment: How is the code above failing? It looks good to me. Did you debug and make sure that you're not hitting an Exception anywhere? Or that your Save() method on the Repository is correct?

Comment: @BrunoLM, Justin: The code of Save method is: _entities.SaveChanges();_

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Account model)
{
    try
    {
        Account accountEdited = accountRepository.Get(id);
        TryUpdateModel(accountEdited);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The initial call to the repository will ensure the entity is in the graph, in an **Unmodified** state. MVC's built in `TryUpdateModel` method will then merge the two objects together (the `accountEdited` object, and the form post data that has been model bound).

This will result in the entity being in a `Modified` state.

Simply calling `SaveChanges()` on the object context will then push the changes to the database.

I have dabbled in techniques such as the "stub technique" but it introduced a world of pain (mainly to do with relationships), so this is the easiest approach, and works well.

Comment: TryUpdateModel successfully merge objects, but the SaveChanges() call has no effect :( No changes in database!

Comment: @Tuizi - huh? Did you run a trace? Anything being sent to the DB at all? Before you do SaveChanges, check the OSM to see your object is there with state of "modified". `ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry`

Comment: OMG the state is Unchanged for my object... why?

Comment: @Tuizi - that is bizarre. Maybe you have to manually set the state to modified (or added) in your Save method.

Comment: I do that with the UpdateObject method?

Comment: Brilliant, saved me a lot of time. I've added a `if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    return View(model);
   }` for validation.

Answer (score 1):

You have your real EF work abstracted from you code you posted. Here is the simplest EF save:

```
public void Save(Account account)
{
    using (DBContext ctx= new DBContext ())
    {
        ctx.Attach(account);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You only need to attach the object if it was obtained in another context. If not you can do it like:

```
public void Save(int AccountID)
{
    using (DBContext ctx= new DBContext ())
    {
        Account account = ctx.Account.Single(a => a.ID == AccountID)
        account.property = somepropchange;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't set state to modified - it will not work.

Comment: It does with self-tracking entities, did not want to interfere with overall objective. Good addition though.

Comment: And also the `ctx.Attach` will throw an exception, since the entity it already in the graph via the initial `accountRepository.Get(id);` call.

Comment: @RPM1984, I stated that in the answer _You only need to attach the object if it was obtained in another context._

Comment: Right, my bad. Read that differently.